# C++ : pointers to vector elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, stdvector

I would like to do something like this, assuming `Lion` and `Seal` are child classes of the class `Animal`:

```
class Zoo
{
public:
    Zoo(std::vector<Lion> lions1, std::vector<Seal> seals1) : lions(lions1), seals(seals1)
    {
        unsigned int i;
        for (i=0; i<lions.size(); ++i)
        {
            animals.push_back(&(lions[i]));
        }
        for (i=0; i<seals.size(); ++i)
        {
            animals.push_back(&(seals[i]));
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Animal*> animals;
    std::vector<Lion> lions;
    std::vector<Seal> seals;
};
```

This doesn't seem to work. It seems to me that it doesn't work when I do `animals.push_back(&(lions[i]));` or `animals.push_back(&(seals[i]));`, something is going wrong with the pointers. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `animals.push_back(&seals[i]);`  Also a bit of a description of why it doesn't seem to work would be helpful.

Comment: I'd like to know "This doesn't seem to work" means, (fails to compile? crashes on program inception?). And why not post Animal, Lion, and Seal declarations as well? In short, give us something that *reproduces* the *problem* (an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)). I have a suspicion about Animal, Lion and Seal but it can't be validated without seeing compilable code.

Comment: [Works here.](http://ideone.com/YZEzyI)

Comment: It compiles, but the pointers seem to be incorrect. Concretely, `*(animals[i])` does not give me a valid Lion/Seal

Comment: @Seub What constitutes a valid Lion/Seal?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's a Lion/Seal whose `numberOfTeeth` is not -19032768.

Comment: @Seub I only wrote the code to show that it compiles; I didn't put any objects into the vectors. That's why you're getting garbage output. Can you tell us what the exact error is for your program please?

Comment: @I sincerely wish I could, but the code is too long and complicated. I thought maybe here I would be told that I can't "safely" do $&myVector[i]$ to get the pointer that I want. Sorry for wasting your time then, I suppose I'll try to figure out what's going on myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that the pointers are to Animals **inside** either a vector of Lions or a vector of Seals. If either vector is reallocated because it grows (when its size reach its capacity), the pointers **will** get invalidated.

Comment: You're right. I thought they wouldn't be reallocated after a `push_back` because I had `reserve`d the correct size, but it turns out an empty vector is reallocated after a first `push_back`, even after a reserve.